# How to close a browser dialog in Robot Framework

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, robotframework, selenium2library

I could't find an answer anywhere, I am relatively new to robot framework.
I need to press a button hidden behind a dialogue from my browser.
It asks me if I want to share my location and (for testing purposes) I have to dismiss it.
I can't select it nor interact with it.

I have already tried to use the :

- "Close Window" keyword
- "Choose Cancel on next confirmation" keyword
- "Confirm action" keyword

But nothing seems to work. What am I doing wrong?
[This is the dialog:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b94Jb.png)

Thank you very much!

Comment: Id recommend AutoIt Library :)

Comment: Is it windows based or web based dialog box?

Comment: Akash, I believe it is web based, you can refer to the link in my question where there is a screenshot, just to be sure. Goralight, what keyword of that library could be useful for my situation? Thank you both for trying to help

Comment: List Windows -  Return all current window handles as a list . Use this keyword and check size of list. if it is more than two then let me know

Comment: It didn't return any value at all. Could it be that I am looking for a result in the wrong place? I was looking in the test report. However, when I run it in a test case of its own (open browser>>Log in>> list windows) it doesn't do anything (apparently), but when I use it in my other script it makes my tests fail.

Comment: can you just post your code which shows how you used keywords and respective errors

Comment: I believe this dialog is a security feature by browser. Because web page is asking for your location, browser must get user's consent before sharing that information. This dialog is not on web page and cannot be clicked with Selenium. Your first options is to configure browser to always accept or deny location sharing. The other option is to use AutoIT or similar to dismiss dialog.

Comment: This may not be desired solution, still plesae try this one.- 
https://support.mozilla.org/t5/Firefox/How-can-I-stop-Firefox-from-asking-me-whether-to-share-my/m-p/530286

Comment: Thank you all for your help, if anybody else will be facing this in the future Hemant Kulkarni's comment solved my issue:
 "This may not be desired solution, still plesae try this one.-  support.mozilla.org/t5/Firefox/… – cit Hemant Kulkarni